# Blender doesn't like FBX 6100 files

Tags: blender, fbx

Blender seems to not want to import a FBX 6100 file. Is there any way I can convert the file, or even better, open it directly from Blender?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the [Autodesk FBX Converter](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives). Unfortunately it is no longer maintained, but it can converts many file formats, up to FBX 2013 format.

Alternatively, if you know a bit of C++ you can write a simple command-line file converter using the [FBX SDK](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-sdk-2019-0).

Comment: The link now goes to FBX Review and I dont see a way of converting it in that program.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Looks like Autodesk removed the link to the FBX Converter sadly. FBX Review does not have the ability to convert file formats, this is a viewer only. Sorry about that!

Comment: Autodesk have restored the link. Just downloaded and it appears to work flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks I updated the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives